git submodule treat as main repo file

Let's assume i have a main repo and submodule in it, something like this:
repo/
├── folder_1/
├── scr/
└── folder_2/

scr attached as submodule like this (.gitmodules):
[submodule "scr"]
    path = scr
    url = https://blabla.com/sub_proj.git
    branch = main

Submodule tree:
sub_proj/
├── base.mk
├── file_1.txt
└── file_2.txt

When i changed something in submodule i see that changed file (in submodule) behaves as part of main repo:

And I expect to see only scr.diff with changed commits like sw split below.
What am i doing wrong?

Probably VSCode git tool works this way, because, in terminal, u can work with submodule like with usual repo, ie you will commit and push to submodule remote, not main remote.

Check it out - cd scr && git add . && git commit -m 'my sm changes' && git push.

@Ryan output of the command:
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean

I can't reproduce your problem (using OSS version of VS Code - called just 'Code' - on Manjaro Linux). Changes in submodule are displayed within separate submodule section, not in main one.

in this project i have 4 more submodules and no one behaves like this one. I'm confused.
